# Kubernetes nginx-ingress remove trailing slash

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, url-rewrite-module

I have a scenario where I want to redirect ingress requests to host "domain" to scheme://domain.com/api?$args

Following is my ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-redirect
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: test-redirect
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/permanent-redirect: $scheme://domain.com/api?$args
spec:
  rules:
    - host: domain
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: test
              servicePort: http
```

Though this works fine, it adds a trailing slash `/` to the redirected url ie `http://domian/api/` which I don't want it to get added. How can I avoid append of the trailing slash

Any help will be appreaciated

Answer (score 0):

Add the following under the annotations section:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/preserve-trailing-slash: "false"
```

or

```
haproxy.org/path-rewrite: (.*)/$ \1   # remove last /
```

[Further info](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/kubernetes/latest/configuration/ingress/#path-rewrite)

Comment: I did , but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: see the second option, hope it works